# Is Haskell's dollar $ operator, and F#'s backwards-pipe <| the same idea?

Tags: haskell, f#

Its been years since I used F#,
and now I am trying to learn a bit of Haskell,
and spot which ideas I can transfer.

Comment: I don't know F#, but having just googled for it and found [this](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/fsharp-pipe-forward-and-pipe-backward/), it appears that it is indeed identical and has a similar main use in avoiding parentheses. (I note that Elm also has both forward and backward pipe operators, and in that language I can confirm the `<|` operator is identical to Haskell's `$`.)

Comment: It's the same idea but IIRC I think Haskell ´$` has lower precendence and is right associative to enable mixing of forward and backwards piping. In F# since `|>` and `<|` has the same and are both left associative makes `<|` less useful I think. Also because type inferrence in F# usally flows from top-left to bottom-right from what I have read the idiom is to prefer forward piping. With that said, I do use `<|` sometimes.

Comment: Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes — they are equivalent. I don’t know F#, but in Haskell this operator gets used a lot to simplify long parenthesised expressions: the precedence of `$` is lower than that of any other operator, so e.g. `f x + y` gets interpreted as `(f x) + y`, but `f $ x + y` gets interpreted as `f (x + y)`. Similarly a long chain of `f (g (h x))` can be written as `f $ g $ h x`.

Looking through a [list of F# operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/), here’s some more correspondences which could help you:

- F# `f << g` ↔ Haskell `f . g`
- F# `::` ↔ Haskell `:`, while F# `:` ↔ Haskell `::`
- F# `<>` ↔ Haskell `/=`
- F# `|>` and `>>` don’t have any corresponding operators in `Prelude` — I wish they did! But you can use `Data.Function.&` and `Control.Category.>>>` to replace them if you want.
- (will add some more if I find any; feel free to comment if anyone has something to add to this list!)

Comment: Haskell got the `:`/`::` backwards compared to just about everything else. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell allows you to define custom operators.
F# |> operator can be defined as such:

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
a |> f = f a
```

F# <|

```
(<|) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f <| a = f a
```

and F# >>

```
(>>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
f >> g = (.) g f
```